Is it permissible to have a man's hair bun if so should it be untied when praying?
Is it permissible to have a man's hair bun if so should it be untied when praying?
It's not like a Camel Hump, it's behind the head and no long bun, example as below;
Please note that there is no intention to imitate women or follow other religions.

